# split lines in a file in perl not working

Tags: perl

i have a file in formatted in this way:

```
string:string1
string2:string3
....
```

i want to scan each lines and split the strings by `:`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open(FILE,$ARGV[0]) or die "can't find file";
foreach (<FILE>){
       @array = split(":");
}
foreach $string (@array){
        print "$string";
}
exit 0;
```

but i'm only getting in output the last line of the file not splitted, for example `stringN:stringM`

what's wrong?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program you write, and declare all you variables with `my`.

Because you haven't declared it you are using a global array `@array`, which is overwritten every time you assign to it, so it is left with just the fields from the last line of the file.

There is no need to explicitly open a file whose name is passed as a parameter. If you just read from the null file handle with `<>` then Perl will open and read from such files automatically for you.

You will also want to `chomp` the newline from the end of each line you read, otherwise the last field from each line will be left ending with a newline.

It looks like you just want a single list of all the fields in all the lines of the file. This will do that for you. It uses `push` to *add* each new set of fields to the array `@list` instead of overwriting what's already there.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @list;

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    push @list, split /:/;
}

print "$_\n" for @list;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're reassigning `@array` each line of the file. Clobbering whatever was in it. So it'll only ever hold what was on that last line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


#open(FILE,$ARGV[0]) or die "can't find file";

foreach (<DATA>) {
    chomp; #remove trailing linefeed
    my @array = split(":");

    foreach my $string (@array) {
        print " -> ", $string, "\n";
    }
    print "End of line\n";
}

__DATA__
string1:string4
string2:string5:string232
```

Comment: i' ve to initialize the array outside foreach?

Comment: You can if you want, but that still won't help. Split returns an array. You're replacing the contents of @array with whatever `split` gave you. So every line but the last, you replace before doing anything with it.

Comment: Because if you don't; you don't see anything but the last line.

Answer (score 1):

you reach the code, I am just modified your code try it

```
my @data;
foreach (<DATA>){
       @array = split(":",$_); 
       push(@data,@array);
}
foreach $string (@data){
       print "$string\n";
}

__DATA__
string1:string4
string2:string5:string232
```

This is gives outputs.

In your code you call the `@array` for other `foreach` loop. Which is only print the last line that is you got. So here i used the `push` function to store the all data into the new array `@data`  then print the splited word in other loop condition. And also you don't use `$_` for the split the data in the first `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use below perl one liner:

**On windows prompt:**

```
perl -ne "if(@list = split(\":\",$_)) { foreach(@list) { chomp;print \"$_\n\";}}" InputFile
```

**On Unix:**

```
perl -ne 'if(@list = split(":",$_)) { foreach(@list) { chomp;print "$_\n";}}' InputFile
```